# php buscar una palabra y guardar en una $variable lo que esta después del caracter

Tags: php, html

Lo que quiero es que al leer un archivo tipo texto, me traiga cierta cantidad de letras despues de una palabra en especifico en php

Ejemplo:

```
$Texto= "php html python java"

$palabra = "html";
```

y despues de buscar esa palabra me traiga lo que esta despues de eso

```
$buscador= ($texto, $palabra,2)

echo $buscador //"html python"
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la combinación de dos funciones de **PHP**, **substr** y **strpos**; con el **substr** cortas el texto y con el **strpos** le dices desde donde lo cortarás, así:

```
<?php

$texto = "php html python java";
$palabra = "html";

$str = substr($texto, strpos($texto, $palabra));
echo $str;

?>
```

Con este ejemplo incluyes la palabra **html** ahora si tambien la quieres excluir puedes agregar la función **strlen** para que sume al **strpos** la cantidad de caracteres a omitir y solo mostrarte las palabras después de html así:

```
<?php

$texto = "php html python java";
$palabra = "html";

$str = substr($texto, (strpos($texto, $palabra) + strlen($palabra)));
echo $str;

?>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Vale, gracias
Me ha servido
Pero puedo decirle hasta donde busque?
Y tambien deseo guardar cada palabra en un array

Comment: Si, el 3er parametro del substr es para eso así: substr($texto, (strpos($texto, $palabra) + strlen($palabra)), 5); el 5 es el limite, puedes colocar cualquier numero